# Iterating through string fails with StringIndexError

Tags: string, julia

**Note:** This question was motivated by this [discourse thread](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/crash-on-examining-corrupted-text-data/29296).

Consider the following example string:

```
str = "This is some text that initially consists of normal ASCII characters—but oh wait, the em-dash is only part of the extended ASCII character set!"
```

Trying to iterate through this string using its length:

```
for i in 1:length(str)
  println(i, str[i])
end
```

Fails with an `StringIndexError`, returning the following message half-way through the loop:

```
ERROR: StringIndexError("This is some text that initially consists of normal ASCII characters—but oh wait, the em-dash is only part of the extended ASCII character set!", 70)
Stacktrace:
 [1] string_index_err(::String, ::Int64) at ./strings/string.jl:12
 [2] getindex_continued(::String, ::Int64, ::UInt32) at ./strings/string.jl:217
 [3] getindex(::String, ::Int64) at ./strings/string.jl:210
 [4] top-level scope at ./REPL[4]:2
```

What exactly is the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings in Julia fully support the UTF-8 encoding standard for Unicode characters.
This, however makes the encoding size of a single character variable, depending on the character.

Standard ASCII characters (code points less than 128) use one byte and produce the expected behavior during the iteration. However, because the em-dash `—` is part of the extended ASCII character set, it produces an error when trying to index using a uniform step size. More on strings and their behavior can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/) (specifically the section "Unicode and UTF-8").

**Edit:** As Stefan mentioned in the comments, note that `length(str)` behaves in the expected way and returns the actual number of characters in the string. The last index position can be retrieved via `lastindex(str)`.

This error can be circumvented in multiple ways, depending on the desired behavior:

**Option 1:** Iterating over the string elements directly
If the index is not relevant, this is the easiest way to go about it:

```
for c in str
  println(c)
end
```

**Option 2:** Using `eachindex` to extract the correct string indices
If the actual index position in the string is relevant, one can do:

```
for bi in eachindex(str)
  println(bi, str[bi])
end
```

**Option 3:** Using `enumerate` to get linear index positions and characters
If the "character" index (i.e. the index/number of the current character, **not** its byte index) into the string and the corresponding character are relevant:

```
for (ci, c) in enumerate(str)
  println(ci, c)
end
```

---

**Edit 2:** Added a small example to clarify.
Using the string `str = "a ∀ x ∃ y"` as an example.

**Option 1** returns:

```
julia> for c in str; print(c, " | "); end
a |   | ∀ |   | x |   | ∃ |   | y |
```

**Option 2** returns:

```
julia> for bi in eachindex(str); print(bi, " ", str[bi], " | "); end
1 a | 2   | 3 ∀ | 6   | 7 x | 8   | 9 ∃ | 12   | 13 y |
```

Note e.g. the jump from 3 -> 6

**Option 3** returns:

```
julia> for (ci, c) in enumerate(str); print(ci, " ", c, " | "); end
1 a | 2   | 3 ∀ | 4   | 5 x | 6   | 7 ∃ | 8   | 9 y |
```

Comment: You may also want to mention that `length(text)` is the number of characters in the string, not it’s maximum index, which is given by `lastindex(text)`.

Comment: Also are you sure that the `enumerate` solution gives byte indices for `ci`? I suspect it may give the character index rather than the byte index. Not at a computer but I thought I’d point that out so you can check.

Comment: Maybe I worded this badly. I meant the character index.

Comment: I think the issue is that you use `ci` for both kinds of indices but they're quite different: `julia> str = "∀ x ∃ y"
"∀ x ∃ y"

julia> collect(eachindex(str))
7-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  4
  5
  6
  7
 10
 11

julia> collect(enumerate(str))
7-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Char},1}:
 (1, '∀')
 (2, ' ')
 (3, 'x')
 (4, ' ')
 (5, '∃')
 (6, ' ')
 (7, 'y')`. Note the former indices are uneven while the latter are always exactly `1:length(str)`.